Цепочки импортов в проекте на python
Есть проект отдела тестирования на python. Множество файлов с тестами и файлов с описанием страниц. Заметили, как некоторые тесты стали сильно дольше ждать подкачки всех зависимостей. Выяснилось, что накопились файлы, которые из-за неверных и беспорядочных импортов ждут загрузки далеких от функционала классов. Вопрос, есть ли хороший способ отследить по проекту некий топ файлов по кол-ву цепочек импортов? Или, например, посчитать память, которая требуется для импорта файлов директории с тестами, всего проекта

flake8 умеет выявлять неиспользуемые импорты.
